# Aggregate Linq Functions

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

All,

I have local data in a List, which has Col1, Col2, Col3, SumNumberColumn as properties of each element.  What I am trying to do is simple is SQL, but I'm struggling to accomplish the same thing with Linq.  What I would like to do is, from List, perform a GroupBy that will ignore what is in Col3 and aggregate SumNumberColumn, but still return an IEnumerable of MyDataType.

i.e. in SQL I would be doing

```
Select Col1, Col2, null as Col3, Sum(SumNumberColumn) as SumNumberColumn from MyTable GroupBy Col1, Col2;
```

With Linq, what I would like to do is (pseudo-code)

```
List<MyDataType> lstAgg = lst.GroupBy(a => {a.Col1, a.Col2}).Select(a => new {a.Col1, a.Col2, Col3 = null, sum(a.Col4) }).ToList(); //lst is also a List<MyDataType>.
```

What would be the best approach to accomplish this?

EDIT: I have seen multiple examples of how to accomplish this and return anonymous types, but I really need to return a List of MyDataType elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return `List<MyDataType>`:

```
var lstAgg = lst.GroupBy(a => new { a.Col1, a.Col2})
                .Select(a => new MyDataType()
                                 {
                                     Col1 = a.Key.Col1,
                                     Col2 = a.Key.Col2,
                                     Col3 = null,
                                     SumNumberColumn = a.Sum(e => e.SumNumberColumn)
                                 })
                .ToList();
```